# How to filter the contents on search irrespective of case sensitive using angular2

Tags: angular, filter

i am able to search the contents based on the keyin. But the parent has its child components,so for Example:
I am trying to filter the contents with `"c"`, if i do so, i get the parent and 1 child, but here i have 2 child components one with `"Check"` and other with `"check_test"`.
When i try to filter with alphabet "c" i must get both the child copmonents irrespective of case sensitive.

TS:

```
searchFacility(search) {
    this.sLetter = search;
    if (search) {
      this.dtFacilities.expandedRows = [];
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.dtFacilities.expandedRows = this.dtFacilities.value;
        this.dtFacilities.value.forEach(m => {
          m.memberFacilities.forEach(f => {
            if (f.facilityName.includes(search)) {
              f.isShowMember = false;
            } else {
              f.isShowMember = true;
            }
          })
        })
      }, 100);
    }

    else {
      this.dtFacilities.expandedRows = [];
      this.dtFacilities.value.forEach(m => {
          m.memberFacilities.map(val => {
            val.isShowMember = false;
          })
        })
    }
  }
```

Here in this section,

```
if (f.facilityName.includes(search)) {
                  f.isShowMember = false;
                } else {
                  f.isShowMember = true;
                }
              })
```

for search, it is taking `"c"`, so it is going for else condition there by making the `"Check"` isShowMember flag as true.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zp74mf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: you could do a toLowerCase() on your search and your facitilityName

Comment: ya even that is also handled in pipe.ts file

Comment: I just tried the code below in your stackblitz and it worked.

Comment: please try giving "ch", it doesnt show the "Check", in my application, with "c" also i am not able to see "Check"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let mySearch = search.toLowerCase();
let facilityName = f.facilityName.toLowerCase();
if (facilityName && facilityName.includes(search)) {
                  f.isShowMember = false;
                } else {
                  f.isShowMember = true;
                }
              })
```